# No-normalized auto-covariance function

Tags: python, numpy, statsmodels

I want to compute the no-normalized acf of a 1D vector `x` in python. I did the following steps:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf
import numpy as np

x=np.loadtxt('MyFile.txt',usecols=6 )

y=acf(x, fft='true', nlags=len(x))

np.savetxt('AutoCorrelationFunction.txt',y)
```

but I can't find in the manual how to set an option to no-normalize the acf.

Comment: What do you mean by no normalized? The acf is correlation like, and so the first value is always 1. Perhaps you want the acovf which is the autocovariance function?

Comment: @KevinS You are right acf is always normalized. I want to compute the viscosity of a system using Green-Kubo relation. I thought that have to do the time autocorrelation function for the non-diagonal components of the stress tensor... looks like is not acf, but I'm not sure if Green-Kubo integrate acovf or what function.... Here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Kubo_relations) they said  "The integral is over the equilibrium flux autocovariance function", so I guess I should use acovf, right?